# Fiddler: how to make a subnet-based filter?

Tags: fiddler

I would like [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com)'s host filter to keep sessions to all hosts on 192.168.2.*

The [docs](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/help/Filters.asp) say that e.g. `fiddler2.com` filter would catch all `*.fiddler2.com` but I can't figure how to do the same kind of filtering for IP subnets instead of hostnames.

Is there a specific syntax? Should I use a custom rule?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a custom rule. Inside OnBeforeResponse, look at the m_hostIP property on the session and use that to set the UI-HIDE flag if it doesn't match the site you care about.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for the answer... and for the awesome tool! Just made a donation.